# Element height not updating after jquery resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On resize it doesn't update the height. Once the load has set it's height, it will then not update despite me updating the variable.

If I take out the lines where it sets the height, then my variable updates fine, but once the height is set it just doesn't do anything.

Where have I gone wrong?

```
var hero_height = $('.hero-image').outerHeight();
console.log('heroHeight: ' + hero_height);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).load(function() {

        $('.hero-image').css('height', hero_height );

    });

    $(window).resize(function() {

        if (hero_height !== $('.hero-image').outerHeight()) {
            $('.hero-image').css('height', hero_height );
        };

        hero_height = $('.hero-image').outerHeight();
        console.log('heroHeight: ' + hero_height);

    });
});
```

Here is a JS fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/5c1za6xa/

Comment: Is there any particular reason you can't just use a % or em property on the image? I don't think you need javascript (or jQuery for that matter) for this and trying to implement it this way is only going to give you headaches. See http://learnlayout.com/percent.html for example.

Comment: I already am using a percentage height on the hero-image and it works as intended. I am simply wanting to add in a fix for mobiles that hide their address bars. When the address bar hides, then the window height is now bigger and so the percentage re-calculates forcing the content to jump as it grows in size. To be honest I've just realized this solution won't work either... Because the height will also update via jquery when the address bar hides... Hmmm...

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 1):

Include `var hero_height = $('.hero-image').outerHeight();` in the window resize function.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var hero_height = $('.hero-image').outerHeight();
    if (hero_height !== $('.hero-image').outerHeight()) {
        $('.hero-image').css('height', hero_height );
    };

    hero_height = $('.hero-image').outerHeight();
    console.log('heroHeight: ' + hero_height);
});
```

Comment: can you upload your code to code snippets so I can get a better idea.

Comment: That's exactly what you posted in your first answer, and I'm afraid that doesn't seem to work as I've already mentioned...

Comment: Do you have time for a call, because I'm not clear the requirements you have given. hero image height and outer height are the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121078/discussion-between-ghayyour-ahmed-butt-and-kinkwilde).

Answer (score 0):

You're overthinking this! You don't need jQuery for this at all, just [CSS media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

Here's an example

```
nav {
   display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  nav {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

This will hide a nav bar on mobile devices (or technically, anything with a screen height of less than 480px). You can obviously change the max-width and styles to suit your needs. This is far superior to jQuery for a number of reasons

1. It's way easier to read
2. It doesn't require javascript, so it will work for users/devices that don't support javascript (which granted is almost no one these days). But not using javascript will also speed up your page loading time enormously.
3. In general (since the release of CSS3), you almost never need to use javascript (or jQuery for that matter) to adjust style. Therefore, since you're trying to change the style/look of the page, you should use CSS. Leave the JS to dynamic functionality of your webpage, not styles.

Comment: And you've completely misjudged the situation - I am doing nothing with nav... My reply above is talking about the phones default UI. You know that address bar where you type the URL into? It will auto hide on scroll... Hence why I was trying to come up with a solution to stop my HERO-IMAGE content from jumping...

Comment: KINKWILDE, you need to clarify your questions better. Your title doesn't accurately convey your question, and your clarifications are vague and confusing.